# How to debounce 'onScroll' in react without using other libraries

Tags: reactjs, scroll, debouncing, onscroll

the code below logs 'scrolled' to the console multiple times (at least 10 times), even though using monitorEvents() indicates a single keydown event.

how can i ensure only a single 'scrolled' gets logged to the console without using external libraries

(i wish to cover all possible events that trigger a scroll, hence why i am targeting scroll and not keydown)

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <section
      onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}
      onScroll={() => console.log("scrolled")}
      style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw", overflow: "scroll" }}
    >
      <p style={{ height: "300vh" }}>hi</p>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your initial purpose. But I can suggest the following solutions:

1. If you need to be sure if the scroll was used somehow at least once, you can simply use the component state to identify it.

```js
function App() {
  const [isScrolled, setScrolled] = useState(false);

  const onScroll = () => {
    if (!isScrolled) {
      setScrolled(true);
      console.log("onFirstScroll");
    }
  };

  return (
    <section
      onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}
      onScroll={onScroll}
      style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw", overflow: "scroll" }}
    >
      <p style={{ height: "300vh" }}>hi</p>
    </section>
  );
}
```

2. If you need to debounce the scroll, you can create a custom hook which will debounce any calls for passed function.

```js
const useDebouncedCallback = (callback, delay) => {
  const callbackRef = useRef(callback);
  const timerRef = useRef();
  
  return useCallback(
    (...args) => {
      if (timerRef.current) {
        clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
      }

      timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        callbackRef.current(...args);
      }, delay);
    },
    []
  );
};

function App() {
  const onScroll = useDebouncedCallback(() => {
    console.log("On scroll debounced (100ms)");
  }, 100)

  return (
    <section
      onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}
      onScroll={onScroll}
      style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw", overflow: "scroll" }}
    >
      <p style={{ height: "300vh" }}>hi</p>
    </section>
  );
}
```

This is just an example of a simple hook that might be improved, but I hope you can use it at the first step.